# String bytes end in 255 for Swift

Tags: swift

Is there any reason why when I run the following

```
var name = "A"
withUnsafeBytes(of: &name, { bytes in
    print (bytes)
    for byte in bytes.enumerated() {
        print (byte.element, byte.offset)
    }
})
```

The last byte is 255? 
I expected the bytes to just contain 65 as that is the ASCII code!

That is, byte 0 is 65 (as expected) and byte 15 is 255 (all the rest are zeroed)

Why is byte 15 255?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct String` is a (opaque) structure, containing pointers to the actual character storage. Short strings are stored directly in those pointers, which is why in your particular case the byte `65` is printed first.

If you run your code with

```
var name = "A really looooong string"
```

then you'll notice that there is no direct connection between the output of the program and the characters of the string.

If the intention is to enumerate the bytes of the UTF-8 representation of the string then

```
for byte in name.utf8 { print(byte) }
```

is the correct way.